# SQL query with 'NOT IN' takes too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL query with a `NOT IN` clause, but it's taking too much time to execute. Could anyone please help me replace the `NOT IN` in the below query.

```
Select 
    RIGHT(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION, LEN(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('-', P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION)) AS Channel, 
    C.CorporateId, C.corporatename,  
    MAX(convert(date,E.C3DeletionVerification))
from 
    employee E, Corporate C, Partners P
where 
    E.corporateid = C.corporateid
    and C.partner = P.partnercode
    and C.Corporateid not in (select CorporateId
                              from employee
                              where DeletionVerification is null
                                and CardNo IS NOT NULL
                              group by CorporateId)
group by 
    RIGHT(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION, LEN(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('-', P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION)), 
    C.CorporateId, C.corporatename
order by 
    MAX(convert(date, E.DeletionVerification))
```

Comment: You can remove the `group by` in the inner query to start

Comment: could you post the actual execution plan as xml and table count,schema

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also: ***what*** concrete database is this for? `sql` is just the query language used by almost all relational database systems - it would be very helpful to know whether this is for `mysql`, `sql-server`, `oracle`,  `db2` or something else entirely. Please add a helpful tag!!

Comment: It's always worth a try to replace the `NOT IN` clause with a `NOT EXISTS` clause.

Comment: There are many problems with this query. I doubt if the use of `NOT IN` is the pivotal factor here. I'd start by fixing the styling in the question, so we can view the query without having to scroll while adjusting to your random casing. Next you need to give us some idea of the schema of your database and provide some sort of execution plan. What database are you actually using? Your problems actually arise from the schema of your data string manipulations and conversions aren't going to help.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Performance questions are usually product specific!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE for your query and use it as below:

```
with emp as (select CorporateId
                              from employee
                              where DeletionVerification is null
                                and CardNo IS NOT NULL
                              group by CorporateId)
Select 
    RIGHT(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION, LEN(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('-', P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION)) AS Channel, 
    C.CorporateId, C.corporatename,  
    MAX(convert(date,E.C3DeletionVerification))
from 
    employee E, Corporate C, Partners P , emp ep
where 
    E.corporateid = C.corporateid
    and C.partner = P.partnercode
    and C.Corporateid <> ep.CorporateId
group by 
    RIGHT(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION, LEN(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('-', P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION)), 
    C.CorporateId, C.corporatename
order by 
    MAX(convert(date, E.DeletionVerification))
```

Note: This is not tested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
SELECT 
  RIGHT(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION, LEN(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('-', P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION)) AS Channel, 
  C.CorporateId, C.corporatename,MAX(convert(date,E.C3DeletionVerification))
FROM employee E
       JOIN Corporate C ON E.corporateid = C.corporateid
       JOIN Partners P ON  C.[partner] = P.partnercode
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM  employee E1
                  WHERE E1.DeletionVerification is null
                            AND E1.CardNo IS NOT NULL
                            AND C.CorporateId=E1.CorporateId)

GROUP BY  RIGHT(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION, LEN(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('-', P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION)), 
          C.CorporateId, C.corporatename
ORDER BY MAX(convert(date, E.DeletionVerification))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query which is slightly changed but I hope it will more effective.

```
SELECT
RIGHT(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION, LEN(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('-', P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION)) AS Channel, 
C.CorporateId, C.corporatename,  
MAX(CONVERT(date,E.C3DeletionVerification))
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN Corporate C ON C.corporateid = E.corporateid 
INNER JOIN Partners P ON P.partnercode = C.partner
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT DISTINCT CorporateId
    FROM employee
    WHERE CorporateId = c.Corporateid
    AND DeletionVerification IS NULL
    AND CardNo IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY RIGHT(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION, LEN(P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION) - CHARINDEX('-', P.PARTNERDESCRIPTION)), C.CorporateId, C.corporatename
ORDER BY MAX(convert(date, E.DeletionVerification))
```